# webpack-dev-server как совместить использование с Open Server

Tags: node.js, openserver, webpack4, webpack-dev-server

Надо **зеркалить** сайт, который находится по адресу на Open Server. В Gulp делал через  Browsersync proxy, на **webpack-dev-server** это сделать также, через proxy.

Пример моего конфига:

```js
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  compress: true,
  port: 9000,
  proxy: {
   '**': { 
               target: 'http://somealias'
           },
  },
 },
```

Но выходит, что сервер возвращает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заметил, что заголовок, где указывается alias, отсутствует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как исправить проблему?

Comment: так же установите Browsersync и проксируйте

Comment: `"changeOrigin": true`

Comment: @nörbörnën ставил, не меняется ничего.

Comment: @Дмытрык полагаю, если не получится решить эту проблему, то установлю **[browser-sync-dev-hot-webpack-plugin](http://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-dev-hot-webpack-plugin)** плагин.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin

Comment: @Дмытрык мне еще hot reload нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `webpack.dev.conf` попробуйте указать такие конфинги (в плагинах):

```
 new BrowserSyncPlugin(
      {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        proxy: 'http://project',
        files: [
          {
            match: ['./src'],
            fn(event, file) {
              if (event === 'change') {
                const bs = require('browser-sync').get('bs-webpack-plugin');
                bs.reload();
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        reload: false,
      }
    ),
```

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо :-). Но хотелось бы прояснить, что интересует, как это сделать средствами **webpack-dev-server**

Comment: Я отмечу его как **Решение** через время. Хотелось бы еще мнения послушать :-)