# Как синхронизировать Webpack + Open Server локально?

Tags: openserver, webpack-dev-server, webpack5

Подскажите, можно ли как то синхронизировать работу файлов Open Server с Webpack.
Что бы проект можно было прослушивать во время npm start, получать возможности webpack но так же читать PHP и БД. С помощью devServer этого сделать увы не получилось. Не совсем понятно как настраивать прокси. Но нашел полезный вопрос тут [StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933319/webpack-dev-server-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-open-server)
Там говорится о дополнительном плагине BrowserSync.
Теперь получается что при команде npm start у меня всё грузится (php,db) и адрес отдается с Webpack но он не видит папку dist/build (в которую при дальнейшем npm run build будет собираться проект)
В целом вопрос такой. Как при npm start транслировать еще не собранную папку dist?

```
  devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
contentBase: paths.build,
open: true,
compress: true,
watchContentBase: true,
port: 3000,
```

},

plugins: [

```
  new BrowserSyncPlugin(
      {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3000,
          proxy: 'http://ссылка на адрес проекта Open server.ru/',
          files: [
              {
                  match: ['./src'],
                  fn(event, file) {
                      if (event === 'change') {
                          const bs = require('browser-sync').get('bs-webpack-plugin');
                          bs.reload();
                      }
                  },
              },
          ],
      },
      {
          reload: false,
      }
  ),
```

],
})

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, можно обойтись добавлением настройки [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) для девсервера, не прикручивая сбоку brwsersync. А о том, как подружить именно brwsersync с Open Server, давно уже попадалось отдельное [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wE-Oi84UJXE), но там сборка фронта на Gupl

Comment: Да, видео я видел. Но в Gulp конфиг у BrowserSync другой совсем.
И я уверен что можно обойтись без этого плагина, но понятия не имею как нормально это сделать. Документацию в вебпак по прокси уже наизусть выучил, а настроить не получилось.